# Error when creating a code between 3 options

Tags: python, variables, input, integer, user-input

I'm in the middle of creating a code that prompts a user to choose between 3 options with an assigned number to each:
Example: Primary: 1, Secondary: 2, Master: 3) and making the number an integer.

The code I have tried thus far is:

```
print("1: Primary")
print("2: Secondary")
print("3: Master")
if inp == 1:
inp = "Primary"
elif inp == 2:
inp = "Secondary"
elif inp == 3:
inp = "Master"
other:
print("Invalid input!")
inp = int(input("Enter a number: "))
inp=int(input( ))
```

The output is works well. However, when I enter a number in the output, nothing happens. I'm trying to get make it so after the number is entered, the output shows You have entered 1: Primary or the level for the chosen number.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please fix your code to show how it is actually indented, because that matters in python. See the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Anyway, think about your code logically. Which step happens first in your code - checking the value of `inp`, or asking the user to supply a value for `inp`? Which step *should* happen first? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
f=0
print("1: Primary")
print("2: Secondary")
print("3: Master")
inp = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if inp == 1:
    out = "Primary"
elif inp == 2:
    out = "Secondary"
elif inp == 3:
    out = "Master"
else:
    f=1
    print("Invalid input!")
if f==0:
    print("You have entered " + str(inp) + ": " + out)
```